SQLite "attempt to write a readonly database error" when trying to READ from the database
I'm using Entity Framework 6 (not Core) and System.Data.SQLite.
I explicitly connect to the database with ReadOnly=True because I'm only opening it to read from it.
The database already exists and is populated with data. When I call .FindAsync on one of the sets, I get this error. If I connect to the database with ReadOnly=False, the same call works fine.
My best guess is the query modifies the database somehow by default, maybe updating some metadata, but I don't know how to investigate this further to confirm that.
What's causing the error? Is there a way to prevent it, without connecting to the database with ReadOnly=false?

Try adding logging and see what it executes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

@Charlieface That page is for EF Core but that's a good idea. After finding the EF6 equivalent and trying it I was able to track the issue down.

I still don't know exactly why, but it turns out my custom database initializer is run twice: once when first instantiating the DbContext (with write permissions), and then again the second time the DbContext is instantiated (in read-only mode...).
The initializer is idempotent so it doesn't do anything once the database already exists and is up to date, but it always calls ExecuteSqlCommand with TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction, which tries to start a transaction, which cannot be done when the database is read-only.
Knowing this it was easy enough to fix the issue.
